# Legend to incorporate Year and Size

Tags: info-visualisation, heatmaps

I have a [heatmap](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/logarithmic_order_quantity/DayofWeek) tab "Day of Week"

Years are color-coded, i.e. more recent years are darker blue.

And size of box is based on magnitude of orders.

How do I create a legend that incorporates both Year and Size?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to combine them. I'd instead **include two scales** because there are two measurements you're trying to communicate.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc4CPg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>